# WP7 creating a loading animation

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have created a custom user control with a progress overlay to get a loading screen like animation. Accessed through Progress.Show() and Progress.Hide(). How do i use these when i am fetching data from an external api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are doing `SomeWebClient.DownloadDataAsync()`, it has a  has a [progress changed event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadprogresschanged.aspx) that you can utilize like so:

```
private static void DownloadProgressCallback(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Displays the operation identifier, and the transfer progress.
    Console.WriteLine("{0}    downloaded {1} of {2} bytes. {3} % complete...", 
        (string)e.UserState, 
        e.BytesReceived, 
        e.TotalBytesToReceive,
        e.ProgressPercentage);
}
```

Comment: But my Custom Loading Screen does not load in the static function.